# Canadian meat/fat "candy"

Tags: food-identification

In the 1970's in Canada (Ontario), I ate this food, it was referred to as "candy".  However, it was some sort of fatback/bacon type of stuff (though I don't remember any meat, it was just soft fat inside the crispy outer shell; also I don't remember it as being particularly smokey), that was cut up into bite-sized cubed, and fried until crispy.  Is this some type of traditional Canadian dish? What exactly was it made of?

Comment: No "canadian-cuisine" tag?!

Comment: Eskimo "Squaw Candy" is smoked salmon jerky. Was the Canadian candy an old traditional food of the natives? Or a more modern thing?

Comment: I have no reason to believe that it was from the First Nations; plus it came from more southern parts, Ontario specifically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what you describe it sounds like [čvarci](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cvarci). In the U.S., especially in the south we call them cracklings (or cracklin's). Basically it is what is left from cubing pork fat and rendering the lard out. Makes a quite tasty snack and from what I read was/is a popular delicatessen snack in some areas of Canada. We often make this with fat from a ham or salt fatback.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cvarci for more information.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like pemmican  (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pemmican), originally an aboriginal recipe combining pulverized meat, berries, and rendered fat.

Note that there are many First Nations in southern Ontario.

Comment: _"The crew had ample provisions-- canned hams, bread, sailor's biscuits, dried fruit and countless cans of pemmican, a staple food made from meat that is dried and ground, then mixed with fat and raisins."_ from: http://www.crimelibrary.com/notorious_murders/classics/charles_francis_hall/index.html

Comment: Pemmican isn't fried, and it's not mostly fat.  It's typically at least 50% dried meat, crushed to bits, then mixed w/ tallow.